# Can I use xpath 2.0 with firefox and selenium?

Tags: xpath, selenium, firefox

I saw other questions referring to xpath 2.0, which apparently simplifies string expressions. I'm using Firefox 3.5.5 and selenium 1.0.1.

- How can I check if my versions of Firefox and Selenium support it?
- Does Selenium defer to Firefox's built-in Xpath implementation?
- In that case, if I start using another (perhaps older) browser with selenium, will I run into problems by expecting xpath 2.0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, selenium uses the "native" version of XPath that comes with the browser. You can make it use a version that comes with Selenium, written in JavaScript. This seems to implement XPath 1.0, based on glancing at the source.

Comment: Just as a side note, CSS selectors are quicker and can be a lot easer to read

Comment: @AutomatedTester: I completely agree. But they don't seem to be as powerful.

Comment: And how to determine which version of XPath comes with the browser ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a jQuery plugin that gives you support for XPath 2.0.  So, theoretically, if you inject jQuery and the plugin into your browser, maybe you could call XPath 2.0 commands with a JavascriptExecutor.   Really, its probably not necessary though, but might be fun to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Currently no browsers support XPath 2.0. To allow the use of a version that comes with Selenium, written in JavaScript, as suggested by @paul-biggar, use the following command :

> allowNativeXpath(false)

more informations here :
http://www.seleniumwiki.com/software-testing/selenium-ide-allownativexpath/