# xpath search attribute with part of string

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am searching element like `find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/requirements/22"]')`

Can I search with only part of it. I mean instead of `/requirements/22` something like `*22`?

Comment: `find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"22")]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Contains :**

```
find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "22")]')
```

**Starts With:**

```
find_element_by_xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "22")]')
```

**Ends With:**

```
find_element_by_xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "22")]')
```

You are also free to try combinations, Example:
find_element_by_xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "22") and contains(@href, "req")]')

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
find_element_by_xpath('//a[ends-with(@href, "22")]')
```

Comment: `ends-with()` is not gonna work - it is a part of XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You would think of using `ends-with()`, but it is a [part of 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936301/can-i-use-xpath-2-0-with-firefox-and-selenium) and is not going to work in your case.

Either use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains):

```
find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "22")]')
```

Or, use *ends-with CSS selector*:

```
find_element_by_css_selector('a[href$=22]')
```