# Selenide - check if link text matches to regular expression

Tags: selenide

Is it possible to find a link that matches to the regular expression?

Here https://demoqa.com/links the 2nd link has a random name that is generated each time with the pattern `Home[a-zA-Z]{5}`.

Is there any way to check if link text matches to the RegEx or simply contains **substring + smth**? XPath `//a[contains(text(),'substring')]` or `$(partialLinkText("substring"))` do not fit because they will select both `Home` and `Home[a-zA-Z]{5}`

Answer (score 0):

First the regex should include numbers as well: `"Home[a-zA-Z\d]{5}"`, and the only solution I can thing of (at least for now), is to iterate over all link elements that contains `Home`:

```
StreamSupport.stream(Selenide.$$(Selectors.byPartialLinkText("Home")).asFixedIterable().spliterator(), false)
                .filter( element -> element.getText().matches("Home[a-zA-Z\\d]{5}") )
                .findFirst();
```

But if you know that your browser supports [XPath 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_2.0), so you can use `matches` function with regex:

```
Selenide.$(Selectors.byXpath("//a[matches(text(), 'Home[a-zA-Z\\d]{5}')]"));
```

Maybe worth nothing the following links about XPath 2.0 support in browsers:

- [Does Chrome use XPath 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455351/does-chrome-use-xpath-2-0)
- [Can I use xpath 2.0 with firefox and selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936301/can-i-use-xpath-2-0-with-firefox-and-selenium)
- [Current XPath 2 Implementations](https://www.w3.org/XML/Query/#xpath2implementations)