# Xpath ends-with expression does not work while starts-with does

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I'm looking for some hint how to use xpath "ends-with" expression. I've got such element to find:

```
<div class="osaiowrhg29875n345" id="react-select-4-listbox">
```

Previous selector I used was:

```
//div[starts-with(@id,'react-select-4')]
```

and its working properly but there are more of such elements and the number is changing so I wanted to catch only the ending of this ID using

```
//div[ends-with(@id,'listbox')]
```

Why its not working for me?

Comment: How do you look up them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is: `starts-with` is available in XPath 1.0 while [`ends-with` was only introduced by XPath 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436789/xpath-ends-with-does-not-work) .
Selenium supports [XPath 1.0 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936301/can-i-use-xpath-2-0-with-firefox-and-selenium).
That's why `ends-with` will not work with Selenium.
But you still can use `contains` with Selenium.
So `//div[ends-with(@id,'listbox')]` can be changed by

```java
"//div[contains(@id,'listbox')]"
```

Comment: yes, that worked..strange that ends-with requires xpath 2.0..

Comment: Right, strange, but this is a fact.